# Modified Bessel Function of the Third Type

Tags: functions, bessel-functions

I was going through a paper mentioning the density of the Normalized Inverse Gaussian distribution. Specifically in the density, the modified Bessel function of the 3rd type is mentioned. By googling around I have not found much on this function and I was wondering if somebody has some resources on how it is derived and what this function entails. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nomenclature is not always consistent. Look at the letter used to denoted the functions. From [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html):
" *The modified bessel function of the second kind is the function K$_n(x)$ which is one of the solutions to the modified Bessel differential equation. The modified Bessel functions of the second kind are sometimes called the Basset functions, modified Bessel functions of the third kind (Spanier and Oldham 1987, p. 499), or Macdonald functions (Spanier and Oldham 1987, p. 499; Samko et al. 1993, p. 20).* "

Comment: Understood, thank you for the help!

Comment: In the R programming language, the modified Bessel function of the third type is denoted by $K_\nu$.